# How can I algebraically prove that $2^n - 1$ is not always prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This question is from *Elementary Number Theory* by W. Edwin Clark.

> Is $2^n - 1$ always prime, or not? Prove.

Is this a start? $x^n - 1 = ( x - 1)(1 + x + x^2 \cdots x^{n - 1})$. So, $2^n - 1 = \sum \limits _{i = 0}^{n - 1} 2^i.$

Will I reach a solution through the above, or is there any other way?

I know that the property doesn't hold true for $n = 1,4,6$ *et al* but I want an algebraic proof.

Comment: I think the question can be interpreted as "prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $2^n-1$ is not prime". Otherwise, as @Hurkyl mentioned, you have already proved your own statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HINT: If $n=ab$, then $2^a-1$ is a factor of $2^n-1$.

Comment: And what would be the factored form of $2^{ab} - 1$? :-)
P.S.: Hey Brian!

Comment: Gee, I wonder: $2^{ab}-1=\left(2^a\right)^b-1^b=\ldots~$ nope, too hard for me. :-) Actually, the really cute way to see it is to write the numbers in binary: $2^{ab}$ is a string of $ab$ $1$’s.

Comment: @DumbCow - try using the factorisation you have given in the question with an appropriate choice of $x$

Comment: @Markbennet: Oh yes, thanks.

Answer (score 14):

> I know that the property doesn't hold true for n=1,4,6 et al.

I just want to clearly point out that this statement all by itself (or possibly with a calculation demonstrating the truth of the statement) constitutes a proof of the question asked.

Answer (score 5):

Take $n=4$. Then $2^n-1=16-1=15=3\cdot 5$ which is not a prime. The statement is proven, that is $2^n-1$ is not always a prime.

EDIT: Why this is a formal proof: We want to prove that
$$\neg (\forall n\in \mathbb{N})(2^n-1\in \mathbb{P})$$
or equivalently that
$$(\exists n\in \mathbb{N})\neg (2^n-1\in \mathbb{P})$$
or even
$$(\exists n\in \mathbb{N})(2^n-1\notin \mathbb{P})$$
Since $\exists 4\in \mathbb{N}$ and $2^4-1\notin \mathbb{P}$, the statement is proven.

Comment: It is a proof...

Comment: @DumbCow This is a proof!

Comment: It should be a formal proof :)

Comment: @DumbCow I believe I now fully justified why this is a rigorous proof

Answer (score 4):

If $n$ is even say $n = 2m$ then $2^n - 1 = 2^{2m }
-1  = (2^m + 1)(2^m - 1)
$ which is not prime. More generally if $n$ is composite then by the formula for the sum of a geometric series we get that...

Comment: I like it :-). So, the main point of our proof is that it is not prime since it has factors.

Answer (score 3):

You might like to ponder why $2047 = 23 \times 89$ is a different kind of example from those already given in previous answers.